# Joomla 2.5: Distinct based on the language website with navigator

Tags: joomla, navigator

I have a joomla 2.5 **bilingual** website and I have the following code in index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
        document.location = "a.html";
    } // ]]>
</script>
```

As a result if you login from your Android phone/tablet it will lead you at the **a.html** link.

What I wanna do is:

Assume the website's url is the www.test.com/index.php?**lang=en** so when you login from android it leads you at the **a.html** and when you login from www.test.com/index.php?**lang=fr**  **should** lead you at the **b.html** .

I need to distinct based on the language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's better to do the redirect server side (i.e. using headers) instead of with javascript

Comment: Oriol> sorry mate, didn't see your message. What do you mean using headers?

Comment: I meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Using_server-side_scripting_for_redirection

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use something like this:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'en-GB' )) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
           if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
               document.location = "a.html";
           } // ]]>
        </script>
<?php }
elseif ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'fr-FR' )) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
           if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
               document.location = "b.html";
           } // ]]>
        </script>
<?php }
?>
```

Please note I haven't tested this so let me know if it work and if not, I can update it.

**Update:**

As Oriol said, it's better to redirect server side rather than javascript. I was messing around with the code yesterday and half of what I wrote worked:

```
<?php
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'en-GB' )) {
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("<?php echo $lang->getTag() ?>");
        </script>
<?php
}
elseif ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'fr-FR' )) {
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("<?php echo $lang->getTag() ?>");
        </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

It basically gets the current language tags and alerts then, depending which language the website is being viewed in. So it will either alert `en-GB` or `fr-FR`. Try using a server side redirect inside the `if` and else `else` statements

Comment: no, it dint't work.
I was thinking something like:

if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) **&& lang=("en-GB")** {

Comment: Lodder> Site collapsed. Just a white screen.

Comment: the Javascript you provided in your question, did that work on it's own?

Comment: The trigger to redirect is if the OS is Android or iPhone. I don't want the redirect to be triggered if you browse the website from a PC/Mac.